# Discord.py Variables specific to Server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, global

i made a Bot that gives People Roles after executing a Command.

Now i want to add a Command that changes the roles it gives People to any Role you like.

When i change a Variable after executing a command like this:

```
@client.command()
async def changeStuff(ctx, now):
    global test
    test = now

    await ctx.send("changed")
```

It also changes on my other Test Server after checking it like this:

```
@client.command()
async def checkStuff(ctx):
    await ctx.send(test)
```

This of course makes sense since its the same script. But is there a way to make it specific for every Server?

Comment: maybe keep it in dictionary like `{"server1": now, "server2": other}` and then you would need some `if/else` for this.

Comment: Yeah im gonna use the server id for that, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out myself:

Here is the Code that will save the Info to a Dict and to a Json File (save that as storage.py to keep the bot below working)

```
import json


replist = {}

def Handle(Name, action, varname = None, data = None):
  if action == "add":
    o = checkInfo(Name, varname)
    if o == "Error":
      addentry(Name)
      addInfo(Name, varname, data)
    else:
      addInfo(Name, varname, data)
  elif action == "check":
    o = checkInfo(Name, varname)
    if o == "Error":
      return "User doesnt exist in database"
    else:
      return o
    


def savetojson(dict):
   with open('varStorage.json', 'w') as fp:
      json.dump(dict, fp)

def loadfromjson():
  try:
    with open('varStorage.json') as json_file: 
      global replist
      replist = json.load(json_file)
  except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    addentry("Placeholder")


def addInfo(Name, varN, data):
  loadfromjson()
  if Name in replist:

      replist[Name][varN] = data
      savetojson(replist)
  else:
    return "Error"


def checkInfo(Name, varN):
  loadfromjson()
  try:
    return replist[Name][varN]
  except:
    return "Error"

    



def addentry(Name):
  replist[Name] = {}
  savetojson(replist)
  return "done"
```

And you can call it in your bot (or anywhere else) like so:

```
import discord, discord.utils
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
import storage

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "+")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")

@client.command()
async def changeStuff(ctx, name, data):
    name = str(name)
    data = str(data)
    
    gid = ctx.guild.id
    gid = str(gid)

    storage.Handle(gid, "add", name, data)

    await ctx.send("changed")

@client.command()
async def checkStuff(ctx, tocheck):
    gid = ctx.guild.id
    gid = str(gid)
    outl = storage.Handle(gid, "check", tocheck)

    await ctx.send(outl)

client.run("yourToken")
```

The first part is from a bot i made a while ago: https://github.com/Lulonaut/Discordrepbot/blob/master/Functions/storage.py (a bit edited)

Hope this helped someone, even if not, atleast it helped me :D